# Keeping certain columns based off of another column with duplicates

Tags: r, duplicates, matching

I have data frame that looks like this:

```
data1 <- data.frame("Site" = c("123", "123", "123", "123", "444", "444", "555"), "Type" = c("A", "A", 
"B", "B", "A", "B", "B"))
```

I would like to have my new table to only keep "Site" that are "Type" "A" when there is a duplicate/repeat of the same "Site" number. If there is only 1 "Site" number, then keep whatever type it is. An example of the output I want is below.

```
 data2 <- data.frame("Site" = c("123", "123", "444", "555"), Type = c("A", "A", "A", "B"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After grouping by 'Site', use a condition to check `if` there are `any` 'A' in 'Type', then create a logical condition with 'A' or `else` return all of them

```
library(dplyr)
data1 %>% 
  group_by(Site) %>% 
  filter(if(any(Type %in% 'A')) Type == 'A' else TRUE) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  Site  Type 
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 123   A    
#2 123   A    
#3 444   A    
#4 555   B
```

---

Or another way to write the condition is

```
data1 %>%
   group_by(Site) %>% 
   filter(n_distinct(Type) == 1|Type == 'A')
```